# 18.04: Bluetooth device does not appear in gnome-control-center

Tags: 18.04, gnome, usb, bluetooth

I have an unconventional setup in which nothing is installed, so I installed `gnome-control-center`, but when I click bluetooth, it says there's no bluetooth devices. However, when I run `bluetoothctl` I can scan and connect to bluetooth devices.

So what's missing for my bluetooth usb device appear in the control panel?

**UPDATE:**

ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth service needs to be running for gnome-control-center to use bluetooth.

Check the status of bluetooth service

```
# systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-01-31 09:32:02 EST; 1h 1min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 8880 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─8880 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop bluetoothd[8880]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop bluetoothd[8880]: Starting SDP server
Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop bluetoothd[8880]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop bluetoothd[8880]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jan 31 09:32:02 ubuntu-1804-laptop bluetoothd[8880]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.34 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```